# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited bot.load_extension

Tags: python, discord

I have my main.py, cogs (folder) and config (folder)
In cogs I have my cogs, here I have ping.py and test.py :

test.py :

```
from discord.ext import commands
    class Test(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Test module ready.')
    
    @commands.Cog.command(name='test')
    async def test(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Test command executed.')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

ping.py :

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='ping')
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong!')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

and my main.py :

```
# Importer les modules
import dotenv
import os
import config.database as database
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import bcrypt
import asyncio

# Load .env file
dotenv.load_dotenv()
APP_TOKEN = os.getenv('APP_TOKEN')

# Initialiser le bot
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# Charger les modules (cogs)
async def load_modules():
    for f in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if f.endswith(".py"):
            bot.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3])
            print(f"Module {f} chargé.")

# Événement lorsque le bot est prêt
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Connecté en tant que {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')

# Démarrer le bot
async def main():
    async with bot:
        await load_modules()
        await bot.start(APP_TOKEN)

asyncio.run(main())
```

When I'm starting my bot I have this following message in my console :

```
C:\Users\SAV-06\Desktop\CastOnBot\main.py:24: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited   bot.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3]) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

And the commande !test and !ping aren't found
Do you have any about the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the `bot.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3])` function.

```py
async def load_modules():
    for f in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if f.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension("cogs." + f[:-3])
            print(f"Module {f} chargé.")
```